# Использование предлога

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, будьте добры, предложить низкую цену в тендере или на тендере?

Answer (score 1):

**Тендер** —  это достаточно новое понятие в нашей действительности, его близкими синонимами являются слова ***конкурс, аукцион, торги.***

Соответственно, управление обычно **сохраняется.**

Мы говорим:  **участие в тендере** на модернизацию чего-либо, победа **в тендере.**

Значение ***на торгах, на аукционе*** также возможно, например: обойти конкурентов **на тендере**, выбрать **на тендере** подрядчика (компанию), подряд будет определен **на тендере**.

Поэтому более ожидаемым является выражение ***предложить низкую цену на тендере (на торгах, на аукционе).***

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки не будет ни с одним из предлогов: важно, чтобы стороны понимали контекст, "говорили на одном языке".

В тендере - в соревновании (предложений цен), в госзаказе, в конкурсе, в конкуренции.

На тендере - на торгах (но и *в торгах* - помните? "Я В ТОРГИ НЕ ВСТУПАЮ"?), на аукционе.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8)) (девушка грамотная) приводит такие примеры употребления:

> Победивший **в тендере** участник нанимает в качестве субподрядчиков
>   одного или нескольких проигравших конкурентов, уведомив или не
>   уведомив клиента. Некоторые участники предлагают существенно и
>   неоправданно завышенные цены на некоторые позиции, чтобы скрыть
>   излишки прибыли победителя, предназначенные для уплаты взяток
>   чиновникам, обеспечившим победу.
>
> Претенденты, прошедшие квалификационный отбор, отказываются от участия
>   **в тендере**. Возможно, сделать это их «уговорил» заказчик или другой участник.

А Справка Грамоты.ру вообще советует избегать предлога (который ещё не "узаконен").

[Вопрос № 215547](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=215547)

> Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сказать грамотнее: "победить
>   в тендере", "выиграть тендер"? А может, как-то по другому?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Лучше: *выиграть тендер*.

[**ТЕНДЕР**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80&all=x) [англ. tender - предложение услуг] *Финанс.* **1.** Письменное предложение, заявка о намерении заключить контракт или доставить товары. **2.** Торги, аукцион по заранее поданным заявкам, содержащим коммерческие предложения цены за товар. *Закрытый т.* (к которому допускаются только участники, отобранные устроителями торгов).

---

[Как участвовать **в тендерах**](https://www.rts-tender.ru/trainings/how-to/how-to07082018)

[Как правильно и эффективно играть **на тендерах**?](https://otendere.com/uchastie/uchastie-v-tenderax/kak-pravilno-igrat-na-tenderax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже отмечено Галиной, **тендер** имеет два основных аспекта: (1) **закрытое предложение**, которое подаётся **на** тендер как (2) **мероприятие** по выбору подрядчика в результате рассмотрения (в оговоренный условиями срок) поданных претендентами предложений. При *закрытом* тендере (иначе это просто "конкурс") те, кто такие предложения подаёт, не видят предложений других участников и *не могут изменить* собственное предложение после его подачи. В этом смысле выражение "**на** тендер**е**" не вполне корректно, в отличие от (подать) "**на** тенде**р**" как на мероприятие типа закрытого аукциона. Соответственно, при выборе предлога нужно учитывать падеж и желаемый смысл. Вариант "**в** тендере" по тем же причинам может относиться к тендеру *только* как подаваемому **предложению** (при закрытом тендере оно подаётся однократно и не может изменяться), в отношении *содержания* этого предложения.